# ANSI escapes in Pash prompt are displayed as garbage in Gnome terminal

Tags: terminal, prompt, escape-characters

I would like to use [Pash](https://github.com/Pash-Project/Pash), a PowerShell implementation for mono on my CentOS box.

After compilation I started it and got

```
$ mono Source/PashConsole/bin/Debug/Pash.exe
[%?%p1%{8}%<%t37%e%p1%{16}%<%t9%p1%{8}%-%d%e38;5;7%;m[%?%p1%{8}%<%t40%e%p1%{16}%<%t10%p1%{8}%-%d%e48;5;0%;mPash - Copyright (C) Pash Contributors.     License: GPL/BSD. See https://github.com/Pash-Project/Pash/
[%?%p1%{8}%<%t37%e%p1%{16}%<%t9%p1%{8}%-%d%e38;5;7%;m[%?%p1%{8}%<%t40%e%p1%{16}%<%t10%p1%{8}%-%d%e48;5;0%;m
[%?%p1%{8}%<%t37%e%p1%{16}%<%t9%p1%{8}%-%d%e38;5;7%;m[%?%p1%{8}%<%t40%e%p1%{16}%<%t10%p1%{8}%-%d%e48;5;0%;mPASH /home/gbuday/projects/Pash> [%?%p1%{8}%<%t37%e%p1%{16}%<%t9%p1%{8}%-%d%e38;5;7%;m[%?%p1%{8}%<%t40%e%p1%{16}%<%t10%p1%{8}%-%d%e48;5;0%;m
```

I was told that my terminal does not understand ANSI sequences.

I use gnome terminal. Is it capable of this with some configuration trick?

Or, I need to use some other terminal emulator software?

Comment: I doubt that any terminal emulator written in the past 20 years would use anything other than ANSI escape sequences. Conversely, applications should use `termcap` or `terminfo` to get the escape sequences for the terminal, so they should work with any emulator. I suspect your problem is something else.

Comment: Also, who came to the conclusion that your terminal emulator doesn't support ANSI escapes and how did they conclude that?  Version numbers would be helpful too.

Comment: You'd need to pipe that through od to be sure, but that doesn't look like ECMA-48 escape sequences, the abundance of %, the matching `{}` are very suspect and I wonder if you aren't getting the uninterpreted format strings (but I know nothing about C#, so could be totally off about that).

Comment: I have no clue what 'pash' is, but if it's simply a shell, and not a full terminal emulator, then it has nothing to do with escape sequences. It is your terminal emulator that interprets them, not the shell.

Comment: Gnome terminal does understand ANSI escapes sequences. It looks like your shell isn't emitting them properly. How exactly is your prompt configured, and what does Pash do with it?

Answer (score 1):

```
TERM=xterm mono Source/PashConsole/bin/Debug/Pash.exe
```

solves the problem. The default

```
TERM=xterm-256color
```

causes the garbage on the terminal. This is not a problem with gnome terminal, not even Pash, but with Mono, see

https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?format=multiple&id=18315

Comment: Neither the answer nor the bug report clarified that the string is a terminfo expression, and that mono handles only the simplest of terminfo substitutions.