# Running Pash on Mono and Linux

Tags: mono, gnome-terminal

I have a problem

[ANSI escapes in Pash prompt are displayed as garbage in Gnome terminal](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/160101/ansi-escape-sequences-aware-terminal-software-for-linux)

```
$ mono Source/PashConsole/bin/Debug/Pash.exe
[%?%p1%{8}%<%t37%e%p1%{16}%<%t9%p1%{8}%-%d%e38;5;7%;m[%?%p1%{8}%<%t40%e%p1%{16}%<%t10%p1%{8}%-%d%e48;5;0%;mPash - Copyright (C) Pash Contributors.     License: GPL/BSD. See https://github.com/Pash-Project/Pash/
[%?%p1%{8}%<%t37%e%p1%{16}%<%t9%p1%{8}%-%d%e38;5;7%;m[%?%p1%{8}%<%t40%e%p1%{16}%<%t10%p1%{8}%-%d%e48;5;0%;m
[%?%p1%{8}%<%t37%e%p1%{16}%<%t9%p1%{8}%-%d%e38;5;7%;m[%?%p1%{8}%<%t40%e%p1%{16}%<%t10%p1%{8}%-%d%e48;5;0%;mPASH /home/gbuday/projects/Pash> [%?%p1%{8}%<%t37%e%p1%{16}%<%t9%p1%{8}%-%d%e38;5;7%;m[%?%p1%{8}%<%t40%e%p1%{16}%<%t10%p1%{8}%-%d%e48;5;0%;m
```

that seemed to be a terminal one but it might be a Mono one. Might Mono not set `termcap` or `terminfo` properly and that causes that garbage to go on my terminal?

Comment: but this seems to be not a unix terminal question -- how can I move it to here where mono experts could say what they know?

Comment: Then delete your original question at unix.SE first, or flag it for moderator attention to be moved here.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in Mono:

https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?format=multiple&id=18315

Using

```
TERM=xterm mono Source/PashConsole/bin/Debug/Pash.exe
```

cures the problem. The default

```
TERM=xterm-256color
```

makes Mono to out that garbage.